# Running jobs on HPC cluster using SLURM

Tags: slurm

Suppose I have two Python scripts: `test1.py` and `test2.py`

How do I write a SLURM script to run these files on two different nodes simultaneously?

Note that: `test1.py` and `test2.py` are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

In a slum script, you can use an array and define two or more scripts as an array element in the Slurm script. An example can be like following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --partition xxxx
#SBATCH --time=6:00:00
#SBATCH --array=1-300

# Job array size will be number of lines in file divided by 
# number of lines chosen below

START=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
NUMLINES=100
STOP=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID*NUMLINES))
START="$(($STOP - $(($NUMLINES - 1))))"

echo "START=$START"
echo "STOP=$STOP"

for (( N = $START; N <= $STOP; N++ ))
do
    LINE=$(sed -n "$N"p File.txt)
    call-program-name-here $LINE
done
```

In this case, you should define resources carefully to run those files on different nodes, or you should have the correct scheduling configuration on slurm.conf

https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#multi_job

> If you want to allocate whole nodes to jobs, configure configure
> SelectType=select/linear